# Unable to load an appbar programmatically

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I am unable to get an appbar to display when I attach an appbar as a resource object to a page.

The following code fails to produce a working appbar:

**app.xaml**

```
    <AppBar x:Key="RegisterHome_TopAppBar" >
        <AppBar.Content>
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Button x:Name="RegisterHome_MaterialsButton" />
                    <Button x:Name="RegisterHome_ServicesButton"  />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </AppBar.Content>
    </AppBar>
```

**some code-behind file**

```
        var view = flipView.SelectedItem as Register.Home;

        AppBar appbar = Application.Current.Resources["RegisterHome_TopAppBar"] as AppBar;

        view.TopAppBar = appbar;
```

**NOTE:
When I use this code, it works fine:**

```
            var appbar = new AppBar();
            StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
            sp.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
            Button myButton = new Button();
            myButton.Content = "Click Me";
            sp.Children.Add(myButton);
            appbar.Content = sp;

            view.TopAppBar = appbar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring UI elements as resources is a bad idea in general. When you do so, you're not getting a new instance every time you access it and use it in different spots. You get one single instance, in this case for the entire application. UI elements can't have multiple parents but if you use that resource in two places or even two instances of the same control you've violated that.

Instead you should use templates as resources, which will generate new copies of the same UI and inject them wherever you use the template. In this case you could put everything inside the `Content` tag into a `DataTemplate` instead and then get that resource and assign it to a new `AppBar` instance's `ContentTemplate` property. That way you get a separate instance each time, but the same child objects and layout.